# How To Print Triple Triangle Pattern in JAVA?

Tags: java

**I just start learning Java and I'm trying to print this pattern in JAVA but my output is not correct as I want. 
 
I want to Print this pattern :**
*Treat underscores as spaces*
**1234554321
1234__4321
 123____321
12______21
1________1**
**Here is code :**

```java
import java.util.*;


public class Pattern
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i, j, k, p, d;
        k = 1;
        p = 5;
        d = 1;
        System.out.println("The pattern");
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < p; j++)
                System.out.print(j);

            for (k = 1; k <= d; k++)
                System.out.print(" ");

            for (k = p; k >= 1; k--)
                System.out.print(k);

            System.out.println();

            p = p - 1;
            d = d + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output I'm getting**

```
The pattern
1234 54321
123   4321
12     321
1       21
         1
```

Comment: In your mind, what is `print("")` supposed to do? What's the point of printing nothing?

Comment: *FYI:* You should fix the indentations of your code, so the code structure becomes evident. Well-formatted code help prevent errors.

Comment: may be I missed it somehow don't rember

Comment: So the missing space was your problem, right? I mean, now that you added the missing space, the output is no longer what you claim it is.

Comment: Not exactly ! now I'm getting this type of output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
System.out.print("");
```

to

```
System.out.print(" ");
```

A space character need to be added in the print statement to get a space in the output.

Also, if you need to get the highest number twice in your output, you need to slightly edit your 2nd for loop from

```
for(j=1;j<p;j++)
```

to

```
for(j=1;j<=p;j++)
```

A `less than or equal to` sign will do that.

Comment: bro after doing this It's like this 1234 54321
123   4321
12     321
1       21
         1

Comment: i have updated the answer, please check it and verify 

Comment: This still gives output that differs from the one described. E.g. the expected result does not have any spaces in first line (1234554321), while the code with suggested fixes gives out a line with space in the middle (12345 54321).

Comment: To fix this, change it to "for (k = 1; k < d; k++)" ("less than or equal" to "less than"). Then the output will completely match the expected one, without unwanted spaces.